PyMuPDF - Prevent PDF pages from being auto cropped
I'm using PyMuPDF to process a PDF and then re-save it, but the resulting file loses the original page orientations and crop boxes. Some pages in the original PDF are larger or differently oriented (e.g., rotated or with custom crop regions), but after calling pdf.save(), all pages become uniformly sized and oriented.
Example:
import pymupdf
pdf = pymupdf.open(pdf_path, filetype="pdf")
pdf.save("pymupdf-exported.pdf")

Original File: https://static.vitra.com/media/asset/8664580/storage/master/download/Factbook%2520Electrification%25202024-EN.pdf
Exported PDF: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mVzAoS8OWHRyM2X_BDABoCCaxAAnrL1x/view?usp=sharing
How can I preserve the original page orientations and crop boxes when using PyMuPDF, so that the re-saved PDF matches the original layout?
My endgoal:
def convert_pdf_to_image_arrays(pdf_path: str, zoom: int, dpi: int) -> list[np.ndarray]:
    """
    Convert a PDF to high-resolution image arrays, preserving color fidelity.

    :param pdf_path: Path to the PDF file.
    :param dpi: DPI (dots per inch) for rendering high-resolution images.
    :return: List of NumPy arrays representing images of the PDF pages.
    """
    pdf = pymupdf.open(pdf_path, filetype="pdf")
    images: list[np.ndarray] = []
    for page in pdf:
        # Render the page to a pixmap with the desired DPI
        pix = page.get_pixmap(dpi=dpi)
        # Convert the raw pixel data to a PIL image (preserving color accuracy)
        img_pil = Image.frombytes(
            mode="RGB" if pix.n == 3 else "RGBA",
            size=(pix.width, pix.height),
            data=pix.samples,
        )
        # Convert the PIL image to a NumPy array
        img_array = np.array(img_pil)
        # Convert RGBA to BGR if the image has an alpha channel
        if pix.n == 4:
            img_array = cv2.cvtColor(img_array, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2BGR)
        else:
            img_array = cv2.cvtColor(img_array, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        images.append(img_array)
    pdf.close()
    return images

Edit: I tried printing the cropbox of all pages
pdf = pymupdf.open(pdf_path, filetype="pdf")
images: list[np.ndarray] = []
for page in pdf:
    print(f"Cropbox {page.number}: {page.cropbox}")

Output:
Cropbox 0: Rect(0.0, 0.0, 612.0, 792.0)
Cropbox 1: Rect(0.0, 0.0, 612.0, 792.0)
Cropbox 2: Rect(0.0, 0.0, 612.0, 792.0)
Cropbox 3: Rect(0.0, 0.0, 612.0, 792.0)
Cropbox 4: Rect(0.0, 0.0, 612.0, 792.0)
Cropbox 5: Rect(0.0, 0.0, 612.0, 792.0)
Cropbox 6: Rect(0.0, 0.0, 612.0, 792.0)
Cropbox 7: Rect(0.0, 0.0, 612.0, 792.0)
Cropbox 8: Rect(0.0, 0.0, 612.0, 792.0)
Cropbox 9: Rect(0.0, 0.0, 612.0, 792.0)
Cropbox 10: Rect(0.0, 0.0, 612.0, 792.0)
Cropbox 11: Rect(0.0, 0.0, 612.0, 792.0)
Cropbox 12: Rect(0.0, 0.0, 612.0, 792.0)
Cropbox 13: Rect(0.0, 0.0, 612.0, 792.0)
Cropbox 14: Rect(0.0, 0.0, 612.0, 792.0)
Cropbox 15: Rect(0.0, 0.0, 612.0, 792.0)
Cropbox 16: Rect(0.0, 0.0, 612.0, 792.0)
Cropbox 17: Rect(0.0, 0.0, 612.0, 792.0)
Cropbox 18: Rect(0.0, 0.0, 612.0, 792.0)
Cropbox 19: Rect(0.0, 0.0, 612.0, 792.0)
Cropbox 20: Rect(0.0, 0.0, 612.0, 792.0)
Cropbox 21: Rect(0.0, 0.0, 612.0, 792.0)
Cropbox 22: Rect(0.0, 0.0, 612.0, 792.0)
Cropbox 23: Rect(0.0, 0.0, 612.0, 792.0)
Cropbox 24: Rect(0.0, 0.0, 612.0, 792.0)
Cropbox 25: Rect(0.0, 0.0, 612.0, 792.0)
Cropbox 26: Rect(0.0, 0.0, 612.0, 792.0)
Cropbox 27: Rect(0.0, 0.0, 612.0, 792.0)
Cropbox 28: Rect(0.0, 0.0, 612.0, 792.0)
Cropbox 29: Rect(0.0, 0.0, 612.0, 792.0)
Cropbox 30: Rect(0.0, 0.0, 612.0, 792.0)
Cropbox 31: Rect(0.0, 0.0, 612.0, 792.0)


So how do I read the source sizes? I've already checked page.cropbox and page.mediabox and their outputs all look the same for all pages. So, I'm missing a configuration in the open which is what I'm asking for help on

I added the result of print(f"Cropbox {page.number}: {page.cropbox}") as an edit to my post. Could you show me how you got varying results? Based on your comments it seems like you know the answer but you're not providing it, just hints

It appears the PDF I was using was corrupted during the script pdf download process. So my PyMuPDF works perfectly and is not faulty

To be honest, I really do not understand the problem. The user's intention seems to be creating a new PDF consisting of rendered images of some original PDF's pages.
The following 10-liner script does this job - without using numpy, OpenCV and what not else.
All pages look like the original and output pages have the original dimension.
There also is no need at all to look at the presence of alpha, because the pixmap creation controls this - and it has no alpha by default.
import pymupdf

src = pymupdf.open("test.pdf")
doc = pymupdf.open()
for spage in src:
    w, h = spage.rect.br
    pix = spage.get_pixmap(dpi=150)
    page = doc.new_page(width=w, height=h)
    page.insert_image(page.rect, pixmap=pix)

doc.ez_save("flattened.pdf")

If desired, pixmap output PNGor JPEG can be used instead of the pixmap directly. This may lead (for e.g. JPEG) to smaller output sizes.
Note: I am a maintainer and the original creator of PyMuPDF.

It appears the PDF I was using was corrupted during the script download process. So my PyMuPDF works perfectly and is not faulty
